# Using mysql '%' in date_format in Jupyter notebook

Tags: mysql, sql, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I try to use date_format in Jupyter notebook in my sql query to get the correct data but Jupyter throws the following error:

```
 sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(issues.created_on, "%Y") as YEAR,  issues.tracker_id as Ticketgrund,  count(*) FROM issues where issues.project_id = '2' group by YEAR, Ticketgrund;"
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

Here is my cell:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlalchemy

session = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pwj@ip/DB")
  
sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(issues.created_on, "%Y") as YEAR,  issues.tracker_id as Ticketgrund,  count(*) FROM issues where issues.project_id = '2' group by YEAR, Ticketgrund;"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,session)
df.head(20)
```

The sql query runs without errors but not in jupyter. Escaping the %, which I assume to be the reason for error, does not change anything.

What can I do?

Comment: Just use single quotes:  sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(issues.created_on, '%Y') as YEAR,  issues.tracker_id as Ticketgrund,  count(*) FROM issues where issues.project_id = '2' group by 1, 2, DATE_FORMAT(issues.created_on, '%Y'), issues.tracker_id;"

Comment: Sadly no, it just changes the error to:
```unsupported format character 'Y' (0x79) at index 40```

Comment: try another:  sql = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(issues.created_on, "%Y") as YEAR,  issues.tracker_id as Ticketgrund,  count(*) FROM issues where issues.project_id = '2' group by YEAR, Ticketgrund;' SIngle quotes around query string

Comment: No it makes no difference. I also tried every other combination of single and double quotes. It still does not work so far.
Thank you @SlavaRozhnev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the % with % (and use single quotes inside double quotes):

```
sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(issues.created_on, '%%Y') as YEAR,  issues.tracker_id as Ticketgrund,  count(*) FROM issues where issues.project_id = '2' group by YEAR, Ticketgrund;"
```

Alternatively, use the date_format function available in SQLAlchemy. Here is a brief example:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, DateTime

md = MetaData()

mytable = Table(
    "employees",
    md,
    Column("emp_no", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("first_name", String(30)),
    Column("last_name", String(30)),
    Column("hire_date", DateTime),
)

row = session.execute( select(mytable.c.first_name, func.date_format(mytable.c.hire_date, "%Y") ) ).first()
print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you @ValerieParham-Thompson, escaping with an additional % was quite new to me.